# How to create a "class" in HTML for my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, web

I am looking for a way to have a navigation bar in all my .html pages without having to copy and paste it multiple times.

Here is the code:

```
<center>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="education.html">Education</a> </li>
            <li><a href="employment_history.html">Employment History</a></li>
            <li><a href="volunteer_work.html">Volunteer Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_information.html">Contact Information</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</center>
```

Every time I make a change in one of the links, I need to make changes in all my HTML files. I was wondering if I could have this chunk of code be a "class" of some sort, and have a reference to it in all my html files with some sort of attribute representing it. So, when I change the list "class" all the html files will be reflected in that change.

Comment: Look into Server Side Includes or any server side technology that includes portions of files like PHP.

Comment: The easy way would be to use PHP, unfortunately if you want to use HTML you don't really have much of a choice. You could use iFrames but that is bad practice these days.

Comment: Side note. The `<center>` element doesn't exist any more. Use CSS to position your content.

Comment: if you don't have chances to use PHP you could wrap your Navigationbar into a JavaScript string. you would need a reference to this js-document on every page and you would need a element (with an specific id) where you could "paste" your js-var with code like this: `document.getElementById("navigationBarContainer").innerHTML += var`

Comment: Look into PHP. You cannot do this with HTML, as it's only a mark up language. For example, you can create a separate file called "nav.html" with your navigation bar code. You can then include that code into your other pages with a simple function like require_once(); Visit http://php.net/manual for more information.

Comment: True you're right it isn't a programming language, ha, thanks for that correction. It's a markup language.

Comment: This question is currently overly broad for Stack Overflow. There are too many "correct" answers to this question, or rather, a single correct answer, "No such thing in HTML". Also, please only include one question.

Comment: The `<nav>` tag is for semantic use only and has no 'effect' on the code.

Comment: @j08691 I tried that, it didn't work in CSS... Maybe I'm doing it wrong but yeah.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I modified it so I am only asking one question, I apologize, I'll probably take down the question too. Still new to this community I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give you navigation a class this way.

```
  <link src="style.css"/>
  <body>
    <center>
        <nav class="navClass"> //giving the nav element a class
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="education.html">Education</a> </li>
                <li><a href="employment_history.html">Employment History</a></li>
                <li><a href="volunteer_work.html">Volunteer Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_information.html">Contact Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </center>
    </body>
```

If you do this to all your nav's and use the same css document for all the pages you can call them in css this way. You will need an external css doucment.

```
//style doucment
<style>
    .navClass{background-color:#FF0000}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a jquery template plugin

Check one out here:
https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template

Answer (score 0):

You could make your menu with JavaScript or as suggested by using a server side technology.

But in clean html you'll probably have to use frames which I wouldn't recommend. There might be a solution in html5 but I'm not sure.

If you're used to OOP I'd recommend the server side aproach.

Good luck!

Comment: I talked to my professor about this today, and yeah, he mentioned to do something along the lines of this. He said that he has a generic layout for his webpages and when a user makes a request on the page the layout will fill up with information from his database. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Most text editors have a Find and replace in files or directory function. Other people have mentioned the likely solutions for server-side solutions - Jeremy Keith's book Bulletproof AJAX proved to be useful for me but requires server-side technologies such as PHP or IIS installed.

Otherwise, I used to create templates using dreamweaver which allowed you to update a menu which then updated all the places that menu was included, but there are probably open source solutions that allow the same thing that people may suggest?